# In DAX, is it possible to check if value exists in another table using measure instead of calculated column?

Tags: dax, powerpivot

I'm hoping to create a measure of distinct count of a customer column, on the condition if customers in this column does not exist in another table's customer column.

I know I can create a calculated column checking if the customer exists, and then use the calculate function filtering out those who do exist. But is it possible to achieve this without creating the calculated column?

Please note this is in Power Pivot, not Power BI so I can't really use 'treatas' or 'in'. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming tables named *Table1* and *Table2*:

```
MyMeasure :=
VAR T2Customer =
    VALUES( Table2[Customer] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT( Table1[Customer] ),
        NOT (
            CONTAINSROW(
                T2Customer,
                Table1[Customer]
            )
        )
    )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works like a charm, and responds to the conditions in pivot table, unlike calculated columns which are fixed in pivot tables

Answer (score 1):

Yes, You can achieve it using EXCEPT()function:

Let's say that we have 2 tables like this:

Customer_Table1:

[image: 121212]

Customer_Table2:

[image: GHFDD]

Now we can use this measure to achieve our result:

```
CountOfDistinctCusts =
COUNTROWS (
    EXCEPT (
        VALUES ( Customer_Table1[Customer] ),
        VALUES ( Customer_Table2[Customer] )
    )
)
```

If we test the code:

[image: FGD]

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin  Yeah, I think so; however people are free to choose whatever answer they want! To be honest, I don't care! In any way, thank you for your time to comment!